# client Event() in processing

Tags: android, processing

I have a project in the processing 3.3.6 and everything works fine but my problem is when I converted to the android studio the method client Event() is not available.

My question is how I can implement that method by myself or are there any libraries could help.
client Event() (If there is information available to read
this event will be triggered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your event() method using the interface . interface provide this mechanism when you get any action then you would get your action listener.

1. create a simple interface in MainActivity class.

   public interface ClintInteface {
                           void onclick(); 
    }
2. make a method in MainActivity class.

   public void btn_Onclock(final MainActivity.ClintInteface clickCallback){
                   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           clickCallback.onclick();
                       }
                   });
           }
3. where you want to apply your own listener apply this code.

   MainActivity.btn_Onclock(new MainActivity.ClintInteface() {
                   @Override
                   public void onclick() {
                       //do your action own onclick listner
                   }
               });

apply this step that would help you to create your onClick() listener method.

Comment: please click the upside arrow that would help me ,for my progress